# apollo-link-state and how do I access the local state / cache?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-link-state

Perhaps I am just not getting what apollo-link-state does, but I figured if I had a "default" value, THAT would show up in my props via the Provider. Yet, I can't locate it. How do you access the "cache" or local state?

I have:

```
import { ApolloClient, createNetworkInterface } from 'react-apollo';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { withClientState } from 'apollo-link-state';
import dataIdFromObject from './dataIdFromObject';

const defaults = {
  NAME: 'Biff'
};
const resolvers = {};

const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const stateLink = withClientState({ cache, resolvers, defaults });

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: stateLink,
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: `${config.url}/graphql`,
    opts: {
      credentials: 'include'
    }
  }),
  addTypename: true,
  dataIdFromObject
});
```

I am passing in an empty object for my resolvers as it absolutely makes no sense to replicate all of reducers that are in the backend. I figured that I'd see the "name: Biff" in the props. Nope.

The store is my "redux" store and is not part of this question. I figured with that "client" prop, I'd see my default. Nope.

```
  <ApolloProvider store={this.props.store} client={apolloClient}>
```

when I log my props in a child component, no sign of cache or "name: Biff" anywhere. How do I get at this local state in my child components. If I update it with a mutation, I should see my components rerender and having access to that new updated local state...but.. where is it?

Comment: On a related note, you may want to revisit the latest docs and update your versions of apollo-client and react-apollo. `ApolloProvider` no longer takes `store` as a prop and does not depend on a redux store, period. That's what the InMemoryCache is for. Similarly, links have replaced `createNetworkInterface`. You shouldn't even be able to import that if you were using version 2.0

Comment: weird, because I do have v2+. I'll look up the additional requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in the docs, you query your local state just like you query a remote server, except you tack on a `@client` directive to let Apollo know that you're requesting something through `apollo-link-state`. So we need a GraphQL query, wrapped with a `graphql-tag` template literal tag:

```
const GET_NAME = gql`
  query {
    NAME @client
  }
`
```

And we use it just like any other query:

```
<Query query={GET_NAME}>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => {
    // render appropriate component depending on loading/error state
  }}
</Query>
```

While Apollo exposes methods for [reading and writing to the cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html#cache), these should only be used in the context of creating mutations for your local state. Querying the cache should be done through the `Query` component and actually mutating the cache should be done through the `Mutation` component. You can read more about writing your own mutations in the docs.

Comment: I'm thinking this won't work for me because with graphql I haven't been able to update my local state/cache with additional data NOT declared in the query. For instance, lets say I have a session query: const Session = gql` query { products: { id }}`, BUT then I run some mutations that update the products with much more info than "id".. they don't show. now, basically I want to "build" up a query... is that possible? As I move thru the app, it needs the data I previously update/mutation.. and its best if I just put that all on a session query.

Comment: It's probably easier to manage the state if it's as flat as possible, but if you want one massive object for managing state, it should still be possible. Either way, the key is when you write an object to the cache to initialize all the properties on that object, even if it's just with `null` or an empty array. You can't just write the `id`, as this will cause queries that request additional fields to fail.

Comment: Either way, if you're having issues with making mutations work with apollo-link-state, I would read the docs, search existing questions then if you still can't fix your issue, post a new question. Your original question was "how do I access my cache", which this hopefully answered.